# UICollectionView navigation bar flashes

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

I have this weird behavior with my `UICollectionview` where, briefly during the initial load, the navigation bar expands into the view and then disappears.

1. The collection view has been added to the view and the first cell added. The first cell is always this static "New Game" button.
2. The collection view is working on adding in the other elements. These are loaded from local storage, and a cell is added for each game that is found.
3. Between adding the "new game" cell and pulling in the game cells, the navigation bar shows up.

Any ideas what could be going on here? Happy to share more information; just let me know what is relevant!

[image]

Comment: Can you try to add a breakpoint while the bar is showing and then inspect your view hierarchy in Xcode and determine the actual `UIView` subclass of that bar.

Comment: Also, any code you think is relevant might help. You should _always_ consider adding relevant code to your question.

Comment: @ndmeiri I figured out that this has to do with my navigation bar. In viewDidAppear I'm setting self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true. If I comment it out then this expanded bar at the top just stays there (https://www.dropbox.com/s/ilib09og2qa4dfk/Screenshot%202018-03-20%2014.09.14.png?dl=0)

Comment: Two things: 1. Is there a better place to put this, so that I can make sure it executes earlier and prevents this flash of the header? 2. The loading I'm doing in collectionview cellForItemAt is slowing everything down, causing this delay in viewdidappear. If I remove that and immediately return the cell, there's no flash of the header. I already have the loading in a DispatchQueue. Is there any approach you could suggest to prevent collectionview loading from blocking viewdidappear?

Comment: Can you try hiding the navigation bar in `viewWillAppear`?

Comment: Wow. So simple. Thank you!!!!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our discussion in the comments, you are hiding the navigation bar in `viewDidAppear`.

```
self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

You should instead hide the navigation bar before the view appears, in `viewWillAppear`.